# Querying a database again and again or storing all the data in a file at once and querying the files?

Tags: database, oracle, etl, talend

I am making a set of Talend jobs where I am going to query same set of tables differently depending on the need of the jobs. These tables are huge. Will it be good if before running the jobs I query all the tables and take all the data from the DB and store them in a file and then using the files for the various queries in Talend jobs. Those files will be stored in the same location where jobs would be running while DB server would be somewhere else. If I am not wrong then DBs themselves have some sort of caching and indexing implemented to make querying faster and optimized. So, is it worthwhile to store them in a file and then query them in Talend Jobs? I am using Oracle DataBase.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this.

Depending on your license, you might be able to use in-memory tables. Despite of that, depending of the size of the query there might be some caching, as you said.

I would avoid it because it could lead to all kinds of problems:

- Filesystem could become unavailable
- No caching in local filesystem, calling this might be a lot slower - even slower than processing
- All database performance helpers - like indices, caching, query analyzer - will not be available
- Need to implement some kind of database system - which is silly b/c there is already a database there

What could be an idea, though, would be a temp table within this or another database.

So the heavy load would only happen once, which I find a good idea. Then the further processing will happen on the temp table. Afterwards, after all processes went through, this temp table will be dropped.

Comment: What do you mean by Filesystem could become unavailable?

Comment: Well, depending on your setup the filesystem could become corrupted or disconnected, e.g. with a mount on a server. With a database hopefully there might be a good replica / failover setup. Interestingly you only picked one sentence of my answer, although all factors should speak for not using a filesystem, this sentence only being a small part of the big picture.

Comment: I took that sentence only because I didn't understand it. Rest I did. Thanks for your help anyway.